# Error when running R function with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to use [rpy2](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2) to run the multi.split function from the [questionr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/questionr/index.html) package.

this is my code

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

questionr = importr(str('questionr'))

data = ["red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green"]
data_vector = robjects.StrVector(data)
multi_split = questionr.multi_split
data_table = multi_split(data_vector, split_char='/')
```

after the last line I'm getting the following error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("c(\"red/blue\",_\"green\",_\"red/green\",_\"blue/red\",_\"red/blue\",_\"green\",_.blue",  : 
 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

I think that it has something to do with the size of the vector that I'm sending because if I remove the last item

```
data = ["red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue"]
```

and then run

```
data_vector = robjects.StrVector(data)
multi_split = questionr.multi_split
data_table = multi_split(data_vector, split_char='/')
```

I get no error message. also if I change the "split_char' var, for example:

```
data_table = multi_split(data_vector, split_char='.')
```

I get no error message, no matter with size of an array I'm sending.

I have tried to run the matching code directly in R (with R-Studio) it runs with not problems.
Any ideas on how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be because the function `multi_split` (`multi.split` in the R package) is trying to use the string representation of the expression associated with the first argument (`"data_vector"` here).

The signature of the R function is:

```
multi.split(var, split.char = "/", mnames = NULL)
```

and the he documentation for `mnames` is:

> names to give to the produced variabels. If NULL, the name are
>   computed from the original variable name and the answers.

In the call `multi_split(data_vector, split_char='/')` the embedded R cannot see the variable name as this is a Python call and `data_vector` is an anonymous variable (only content, no variable name).

I though that you could specify `mnames`, but you checked and this not working (see comments below). That's what the code seems to say: the line `vname <- deparse(substitute(var))` is evaluated no matter mnames is specified or not: https://github.com/juba/questionr/blob/9cf09f3ffcd6c8df24182380f12d52b061c221ef/R/table.multi.R#L161

The alternative is to work out the use of an R expression. An older post should provide the necessary bits for that: [What object to pass to R from rpy2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183853/what-object-to-pass-to-r-from-rpy2)

A third possibility is to creatively mix Python-strings-as-R-code:

```
data = ["red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green", "red/green", "blue/red", "red/blue", "green"]
data_vector = robjects.StrVector(data)
# binding the R vector to a symbol in R's "GlobalEnv"
robjects.globalenv['mydata'] = data_vector
# the call is now in a Python string that is evaluated as R code
data_table = robjects.r("multi.split(data_vector, split_char='/')")
```

Comment: I have tried to add the `mnames` parameter as you can see here: `data_table = multi_split(data_vector, split_char='/', mnames=robjects.StrVector(['a', 'b']))` but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: OK. I updated the answer. Hopefully one of the options is workable for you. Whenever the R code is using the unevaluated expression as a string to create labels or variables names, the use of anonymous objects can create trouble.